# Git Post-receive hook get modified files/foldes

Tags: git, hook, git-post-receive

I'm writing a post-receive hook to update some servers.

My git repo has a folder for each server. My objective is get all folders (servers) that has modified to ran some scripts on only those servers.

Here is an example of my working tree:

```
├── host1
│   ├── examplefile.json
│   └── configfile.cfg
├── host2
│   └── file1.txt
├── host3
│   └── binfile.rpm
```

It's possible to write something like that on post-receive?

**UPDATE 1**:
My post-receive so far execute a script on another server witch has a copy of this repo, this server than fetch, reset and execute a script to update those files on every host.

Comment: So you want to execute code based on what server receives an update from git? If so, yes, that is possible.

Comment: hello @blcook223, no, that's not the point. Read my update, now it's more clear haha

Answer (score 0):

What i've just figured out it's much more simpler to ran a diff on the server that post-receive execute:

My **post-receive** it's just a command over ssh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh root@controller-host -C /root/sync.sh
```

**Sync script on controller host**:

```
cd /root/mytest/myrepo
git fetch --all
git diff --name-only origin/master
git reset --hard origin/master
git diff --name-only origin/master
```

OUTPUT:

```
Fetching origin
host1/file1
host2/file1
host3/file1
host4/file1
HEAD is now at 8e57e51 startei
```

Now it's possible to parse the diff output an syncronize only host1,host2,host3 and host4.

If someone find a better way please share.